# Pegar tamanho X de uma PictureBox?

Tags: .net, c++

Tenho uma *Picture Box*, e em certa parte do código eu edito o tamanho horizontal (x) dela, ai depois mais em baixo no código, eu preciso editar apenas o tamanho vertical (y). Eu quero que o tamanho de (x) continue o mesmo que estiver atualmente.

Só um exemplo:

```
pb->Size = System::Drawing::Size(2, 110 + 8);
pb->Size = System::Drawing::Size(AQUI SERIA ALGO QUE CONTENHA O VALOR ATUAL DE X, 110 + 9);
```

Ou alguma outra alternativa que chegue ao mesmo resultado.

Lembrando que eu quero o tamanho x e não a localização x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode ler a largura atual através da propriedade `Width`, assim:

```
pb->Size = System::Drawing::Size(pb->Size.Width, 110 + 9);
```

Mas se quer mesmo é só mudar o valor da altura, sugiro ir diretamente mudar o valor da altura:

```
pb->Size.Height = 110 + 9;
```

Mais detalhes na documentação: [`System::Drawing::Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Em .NET No C++ Só Se Usa O "." Para As Variáveis ?

Comment: Se usa `->` quando a variável da esquerda é um ponteiro, como `pb`. Mas se usa `.` se for um referência direta, como `pb->Size`. Nesse respeito, o C++ é idêntico ao C.